# Java Throwing exceptions vs returning response in catch

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception

I know a lot has been discussed around exception handling, however I need some advice specific to my situation.

I am currently working on a `Spring MVC` application with `Controller->Services->DAO` layers. The service classes catch mainly two kinds of exceptions `HibernateException` and `IOException`.

`HibernateException` because service needs to perform rollback if a transaction did not succeed and `IOException` since it is an unchecked exception and needs to be caught or thrown and I prefer the first option.

Now what would be a better way of handling these further up in the stack :

1. Should I rethrow these exceptions to the controller and in the
   `ExceptionHandler` of the controller send a HTTP error-code 500
2. Or in the catch block create the normal `JSON response` object, setting `status=failure` and the appropriate error message and return this to the Controller?

Comment: You should go with your point 1.

Comment: `IOException` is _not_ an unchecked exception, technically; what do you mean here?

Comment: I'd catch the checked exceptions and rethrow them wrapped as a custom runtime exception if you cannot handle them otherwise.

Comment: Why not both?  If the front end wants JSON to report the error, you can return it as the body of a 500 return.

Comment: @fge I mean I am using IO methods which need the exception to be caught or add a throws clause to the method signature

Comment: "fail fast" approach is IMO way to go: just return 500. http://www.rps-obix.com/docs/manuals/fail_fast_principle.html

Comment: I personally use the @Transaction annotations and let it handle the rollbacks and keep Hibernate exceptions out of my service tier. Nothing says "Hibernate" in my Service tier. Doing this I use the second approach and just return a JSON response detailing what is happening.

Comment: bh5k I would not use @Transaction annotations for the reason that my services are doing more than just accessing the database such as sending email, reading/writing to files, and I wouldn't want these to be part of transactions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Exception Handling convensions:***

There is a saying that, *best way of handling Exception is not to handle it!*

For `Spring`'s convention of `controller<->service<->dao` layers, `Exception` handling mechanism is known as `Bubble up`. Any exception occurs in the `dao` or `service` layer, you should pop it up to the `controller` layer (by adding `throws XXXException` in dao and service layer's method signature, is the most common way). Only `controller` layer should handle Exceptions.

Here is a nice tutorial of how you can [handle exceptions for REST with spring](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring-3-2.html).

***Send HTTP Status code 500 or JSON object with status:***

Sounds like you are writing API with `Spring MVC`. Look, when you are writing API's you should follow the proper conventions. It is Globally accepted that for internal server errors you send HTTP response with code `500`, that means internal server errors.

There are number of causes for what you should not send `JSON` response in this case. One of the main cause is the implicit assumption of your API client. That is HTTP response with code `200` with a `JSON` object means every thing went normal. And thus the client side business logic may reflect that assumption which is wrong eventually.

Here you can see some `API` error code conventions for some well-known organizations:

- [twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses)
- [LinkedIn](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/request-and-response-headers)
- [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors)

Comment: Thanks for the insightful response. I am developing a Spring MVC app with jquery client mainly using ajax. I think whether it's an api or not proper error handling is important to be consistent throughout the application. I shall follow your advice, if the webservice executes sucessfully send HTTP response 200 and in case of exceptions send appropriate HTTP error response codes.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have not come so far yet as to create a client and therefor can pick 100% for yourself.

If so I would also recommend to use 1, for the main reason that using the correct status codes can go a long way in your API, as well as it's a very easy solution to your problem. You can write some neat code for your error handling. 
Another major reason why you should use your first point is because you can easily re-use the error handling for other APIs, resources or webapps.

For example an enum with all your errors, and what status code you consider them to be, and you can also include what log level you want them to be.

```
public enum ExceptionMapping {
IllegalArgumentException(IllegalArgumentException.class, 400, LogLevel.ERROR),
```

If your goal is to build a neat API for unknown clients I would recommend reading more about REST level 3 (http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) where you includes hypermedia links to create an API which allows the client to "browse" your full API. It's more work for the client since they have to be smarter but it can provide you with very nice features such as breaking a large part of your API without the client even noticing.

Comment: +1 for the insightful link. I am already working on a jquery client, however still can make changes since I am single handedly working on the server and client.