# How do you design a services layer that's not all try/catch blocks?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

When designing a SpringMVC application the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation is at our disposal in the REST layer. This greatly de-clutters controller methods by offloading exception handling to a set of semi-generic handlers.

The basic architecture of our services is this:

> [REST API]  <==> [Application Services] <==> [Data Layer]

I'm of the belief that a REST layer controller should not be dealing directly with Data layer exceptions, instead it should be dealing with Application Service exceptions only.

However, that means all my Application Services methods basically have to look like this:

```
public DomainObject getSomeDomainObjectById(String id) {
   DomainObject retVal = null;
   try {
      myDomainDao.getSomeDomainObjectById(id);
   } catch (DataLayerExceptionOfSomeSort ex) {
      throw translateToAppropriateServiceException(ex);
   }
   //do some further processing
   return retVal;
}
```

To me, that's a lot of in-your-face exception handling, which I don't care for. How else could I solve this? Is there an easy way to achieve the same thing in the Application Services layer as there is in the Rest layer?

My first thought is AOP. I'm open to this providing it doesn't add a lot of cruft and is easy to configure.

Comment: Depending on your specifics, Spring does provide some exception-translation framework. For what it's worth, I write my REST tier to communicate with my business tier through a DTO (such as a Spring HATEOAS `ResourceSupport`) and throw appropriate exceptions from the business tier to represent, for example, object-not-found.

Comment: Personally I don't throw checked exceptions in the data layer. You will notice Spring JDBC follows this same principal.

Comment: @GriffeyDog yeah, I realize that. However I think it's bad design to be dealing with those exceptions (checked or unchecked) that are thrown from the data layer at the REST layer. The Business Services layer should translate them (somehow)

Comment: This depends largely on whether there's anything the REST layer *can* do about it. If some object isn't found, then why not let an exception annotated with a 404 status instruction pop all the way up to the `DispatcherServlet`?

Comment: Translate them to what? They are generally non-recoverable, which makes unchecked the way to go. Let them bubble up to a layer that can "handle" them (logging, notifications, etc.).

Comment: @GriffeyDog Let's say you have a Business Layer method: purchaseCart(Cart). It processes each item in the cart by updating an inventory system and processing payment. There is a constraint in the Inventory DB that says "units > 0" and it's been violated. Do you want the error that is propagated up to the REST layer to be some database error, or do you want it to be a Service layer exception, say "OutOfStockException" which provides details about the item which is out of stock?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't have the service layer dealing with translating DB constraint violations. Only the data access layer should know anything about the DB behind it, so if there's an exception to translate I would do it there. I would consider "out of stock" to be a recoverable event, and would probably use something (e.g. return a status code) besides checked exceptions to deal with it at layers above the data layer.

Comment: I'm really starting to gain appreciattion for Scala's `Either` datatype :P

Comment: Right, and if throwing an exception for "out of stock" from your data layer makes the most sense for your design, do so. But I do recommend limiting checked exceptions to recoverable conditions.

Comment: @ThaDon - How did you end up handling this scenario? I have a similar scenario and was wondering if aspects are a good choice?

Answer (score 2):

You should use AOP, with or without Spring and do in your aspects this kind of work (like exception translation, transaction management, etc).

Answer (score 0):

A really good approach is to use the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-controller-advice

With @ControllerAdvice I was able to implement standard JSON error object https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_what_about_errors that is returned from the @ControllerAdvice

To Represent the standard errors I created a standard api exception hierarchy with classes such as `RestApiError`, ResourceNotFoundException(RestApiError error), BadRequestException (RestApiError) .... etc.

The exceptions are unchecked and the controller advice catches all exceptions and classifies into the standard error messages which are then returned to the user.

Comment: I'm clear on how to handle at the REST layer, but the question is how to emulate this in the Business layer.

Comment: Or are you suggesting what this fellow is suggesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16900358/33689 basically, handle DAO errors up at the controller level?